# Make jQuery UI Selectmenu "Not change" the value on 'change' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am using the 'fnagel jQuery UI Selectmenu Widget' that you can find [here](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu).
I want make the widget **not select** the new option when **change** event is fired based on some condition.

Usually this is accomplished by '`return false;`' from the change event. But its not working. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunakv1/TFquL/1/) here.

Can some one please help me make the fiddle work by not selecting the value on change event?

Thanks!

Comment: There is an [enhancement logged for this](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/pull/130) with a pull request - it has not yet been implemented.

Comment: So I cant get this fixed till they implement it?

Comment: `return false` won't work until it is fixed. @VikDavid has a workaround below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually save and revert the value, [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ec2Jg/).

1. Add a data attribute to your select element:

   ... data-prev-selected="1" ...
2. Use this code for the change event:

   ```
   var someCondition = true; // hardcoded for now

   // Undo new selection
   if ( someCondition ) {
       var prevIdx = $('select#speedA').attr('data-prev-selected');
       $('select#speedA').selectmenu("index", prevIdx);
       return;
   }

   // Save new index
   var idx = $('select#speedA').selectmenu("index");
   $('select#speedA').data('data-prev-selected', idx);
   ```